# How do I specify the API version in a Facebook batch API request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A Facebook batch API request allows the caller to specify multiple API endpoints in a single HTTP POST.

The post is made to a base URL: https://graph.facebook.com.

The body of the post contains a JSON hash with relative URLs to call in the "relative_url" field, e.g. "me/feed".

How do I specify an API version in this call?

For example, to hit the 2.2 version of the API, do I post to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/ or do I specify "v2.2/me/feed" in the relative_url?

As of Feb 26, 2015 the Facebook API documentation is not clear on this point:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: The answer below by Slartibartfast seems to be correct, but for future posts; please note what you have tried already. Did you try both methods of creating a batch request, and results did you get?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have to put in the relative url . Here's an [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/batch-requests) from the marketing batch API docs

```
curl -F 'access_token=______' 
  -F 'test1=@./test1.jpg'  
  -F 'batch=[
             {
              "method": "POST",
              "name": "create_creative",
              "relative_url": "<API_VERSION>/act_187687683/adcreatives",
              "attached_files": "test1",
              "body": "title=Test title&body=Test body&link_url=http://www.test12345.com&image_file=test1.jpg"
             },
             {
              "method": "POST",
              "relative_url": "<API_VERSION>/act_187687683/adgroups",
              "body": "campaign_id=6004163746239&redownload=1&bid_type=CPC&bid_info={\"clicks\":150}&creative={\"creative_id\":\"{result=create_creative:$.id}\"}&targeting={\"countries\":[\"US\"]}&name=test1"
             },
             {
              "method": "POST",
              "relative_url": "<API_VERSION>/act_187687683/adgroups",
              "body": "campaign_id=6004163746239&redownload=1&bid_type=CPC&bid_info={\"clicks\":150}&creative={\"creative_id\":\"{result=create_creative:$.id}\"}&targeting={\"countries\":[\"GB\"]}&name=test2"
             },
             {
              "method": "POST",
              "relative_url": "<API_VERSION>/act_187687683/adgroups",
              "body": "campaign_id=6004163746239&redownload=1&bid_type=CPC&bid_info={\"clicks\":150}&creative={\"creative_id\":\"{result=create_creative:$.id}\"}&targeting={\"countries\":[\"IE\"]}&name=test3"
             }
            ]' https://graph.facebook.com/
```

I'm assuming this is common to other requests as well.

Various other sources for reading

1.) From [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview)

> Pre-pend the version identifier to the start of the request path. For
>   example, here's a call to v2.2:
>
> ```
> GET graph.facebook.com
>   /v2.2/me
> ```
>
> This works for all versions, in this general form:
>
> ```
> GET graph.facebook.com
>   /vX.Y/{request-path}
> ```

2.) Putting it in the url seems to be for [Dialogs and Social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions)

> Dialogs
>
> Versioned paths aren't just true for API endpoints, they're also true
>   for dialogs and social plugins. For example, if you want to generate
>   the Facebook Login dialog for a web app, you can prepend a version
>   number to the endpoint that generates the dialog:
>
> ```
> https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?
>   client_id={app-id}
>   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
> ```
>
> Social Plugins
>
> If you're using the HTML5 or xfbml versions of our social plugins, the
>   version rendered will be determined by the version specified when
>   you're initialising the JavaScript SDK.
>
> If you're inserting an iframe or plain link version of one of our
>   plugins, you'd prepend the version number to the source path of the
>   plugin:
>
> ```
> <iframe
>  src="//www.facebook.com/v2.0/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80&amp;appId=634262946633418" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"> </iframe>
> ```

Comment: What I really want is for someone from *Facebook* to give us the Facebook approved answer, then update the authoritative docs. In lieu of that, I think you are likely right.

Comment: Well @Flaxfield who's commented on your question seems to be a dev sup engineer at Facebook (from his profile) so I guess thats the closest you'll get on SO :)